# ssh_channel_open_forward none blocking

Tags: c, ssh, libssh

I am trying to implement ssh client with libssh.

According libssh doc: http://api.libssh.org/stable/group__libssh__channel.html#gae86b0704a1f2bdebb268b55567f7f47b ssh_channel_open_forward is supporting none block mode.

Here is my sequence:

```
1. ssh_new ()
2. ssh_set_blcoking (session, false)
3. ssh_connect ()                                      :None Blocking -> OK
4. ssh_userauth_password (session, NULL, "password")   :None Blocking -> OK
5. ssh_channel_new (session)
6. ssh_channel_set_blcoking (channel, 0)
7. ssh_channel_open_foward(...)                        :Bocking       -> NG
```

I am sure that the same code on MaxOS(X) ssh_channel_open_foward function is none blcoking.
On linux(ubuntu) and Win32(win7/xp) ssh_channel_open_foward is blocking.

also, add test code: assert (ssh_is_blocking (session_->session ()) == 0). assert is never happened, that means the channel is already switched to none block mode. But ssh_channel_open_foward never returns SSH_AGAIN. it is totally blocked.

Any help will be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault. I check out the master of libssh. And rebuild it on Linux and win32. This problem was fixed.